# field_attach_update and field_get_items for anonymous users

Tags: 7, entities

Is there a way to benefit from `field_attach_update` and `field_get_items` functions for both anonymous and logged in users? Or do I have to use raw `$_SESSION` for anonymous users and after they log in (or register) switch to fields API? Note that I want to store different data for each anonymous user.

Comment: The FieldAPI does not only work logged in users. Nodes and Fields work for anyone with the correct Permissions. By default Drupal does not let anonymous users post new content (eg, nodes and their fields). I'm not sure what your question is...

Comment: @tenken I did some tests and it seems that when I do `field_attach_update` for anonymous user then the value is stored for all anonymous users. I want it to be stored for particular anonymous user only.

Comment: The `anonymous user` in Drupal is user `uid = 0`. Yes, its 1 thing. If you want to store other data you have to use cookies, session data, maybe a webform and retrieve it later ..... dunno.